# C# Google Drive SDK Why I cannot search item by its name?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have strange problem.

I have some folders in my Google Drive, and one is named `myFolder`. That folder has visibility option set to `Anyone with the link`.

I want to get that folder ID. To do so, I have the following code

```
ChildrenResource.ListRequest request = Google_DriveService.Children.List("root");

request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title='myFolder' and trashed=false";

try
    {
        ChildList children = request.Fetch();

        return children.Items;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
```

which throws error 500. But, if I change the query to `"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";` I get the list of the folders, but there is no posibility to know which folder in that list is the one that I want.

So

1) why I get that error 500 if I pass the folder name inside that query ?

2) How to get folder details (e.g. its name) if I have ID ?

### EDIT

OK, I've changed the code as you guys suggested, now I don't get the error, but the folder is still not found. It is placed in the `root` folder.

```
 var request = Google_DriveService.Files.List();

 request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title='myFolder' and trashed=false";

 var children = request.Fetch();

 return children.Items.Count > 0 ? children.Items.First().Id : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

1 . Probably a Bug. Try running your query from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it to confirm

What scope are you using? If **drive.file**, try switching to **drive**

2 . In the returned JSON, look for 'title'. If you need to be sure it's the right file, you maybe need to check the parent id vs the parent id of myfolder.

Comment: 1) even on that page you posted I get the error 500, so it must be a bug

Comment: 2) the returned files list contains the following string properties: Id, ETag, Kind, SelfLink

Comment: Don't use the ChildrenResource. Just use Files

Comment: done. But the folder is not found, check my post edit

Comment: sorry I should have explained. to find the children of folder myfolder, you need 2 calls (unless you've cached the item ID of myFolder). First do your files query to find Myfolder and get its ID. Then do a second files query with 'parent = myfolder_item_id'.

I strongly suggest you prototype all of this using  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it before you spend much time coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the root you have in there.  This works. Not sure which client api you are using.  This is using the latest.

```
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.MaxResults = 1000;
request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and title='myFolder'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet uses Google.Apis.Drice.V2 Client Library that can be used for locate a folder in Google Drive.

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Discovery;
using Google.Apis.Upload;   

string search = string.Format("title = '{0}' and mimeType = 
'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",folderName);

    IList<File> files = new List<File>();                
    try
        {

            //List all of the files and directories for the current user.  
            // Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
            FilesResource.ListRequest list = _service.Files.List();
            list.MaxResults = 1000;
            if (search != null)
            {
                list.Q = search;
            }
            FileList filesFeed = list.Execute();

            //// Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
            while (filesFeed.Items != null)
            {
                // Adding each item  to the list.
                foreach (File item in filesFeed.Items)
                {
                    files.Add(item);
                }

                // We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is
                // null.
                // If this is the case, break.
                if (filesFeed.NextPageToken == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Prepare the next page of results
                list.PageToken = filesFeed.NextPageToken;

                // Execute and process the next page request
                filesFeed = list.Execute();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // In the event there is an error with the request.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```